# C# Grab HTML from a Browser Window

Tags: c#, html, browser, screen-scraping, cefsharp

I want be able to somehow, get access of a open Webbrowser (like Chrome or Firefox) and Grab the HTML text from it. Then Load this HTML in my C# program and read important stuff out of it.
and this should happen once a second.

The reason why i need to go this unusual way is, i cant use the webbrowser that is integratet in WPF because the website i want to parse says that the browser is to old.
The CEFSharp Webbrowser works in 99% of all cases really fine and i am doing this currently with this browser BUT it cant handle an incoming H.264 Webcamstream witch is a red flag.

so i have no idea how i can force the cefbrowser to my 100% usability. that is why i need desperately i tipp or a hint from you guys ho i could grab the HTML text from my chrome browser.

thank you for your help =)

Comment: Habe you tried the [Google api's for .net](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis)?

Comment: No i dont had this in mind yet, but i will have a look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best approach i had is selenium.
i use the chromewebdriver to start a chrome browser and from this i can get my stuff.